# Connecting Flash Programming SWF file in asp.net and need to store some values in data

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, flash, flash-cs5

I am having some doubts in flash , asp.net and SQL or any database connectivity :

- First i have created a swf flash program with some text box and button
- Second, if i click that button means it will need to save in database
- Third, how to connect the created  swf file in asp.net and in database also.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: thanks ElYusubov for re-correcting the correct way of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:** all the steps that you have described do sum up on a concept of **passing data between flash swf and asp.net**. There are plenty of references that you may use, however, here you are some good posts to follow:

- [Pass Values Between Flash and Asp.net](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/9dc40276-0cd3-4346-8abd-90b3aa7d5cb7)
- [Thread: Passing variables to Flash](http://www.aspmessageboard.com/showthread.php?230681-Passing-variables-to-Flash)
- [Passing variables from asp.net to flash](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?360922-Passing-variables-from-asp-net-to-flash)
- [Passing FlashVars from C# to run swf in a player](http://allitinfo.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/passing-flashvars-from-c-to-run-swf-in-a-player/)

Comment: s s bro.. need to retrieve user defined values and using the flash file which is integrated in ASP.NET and need to store the values in database.. which back-end is best for this solution..